# Using @StateObject in iOS 14.0 while supporting iOS 13.0

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios14

I need help finding the best way to support the new @StateObject in iOS 14.0 and still supporting some alternative in iOS 13.0. Admittedly, I do not know what is the best approach in iOS 13.0. Below is what I currently have.

Does anyone have ideas on a better approach?

```
struct HomeView: View {
    let viewModel: HomeViewModel

    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            HomeViewWrapper(viewModel: viewModel)
        } else {
            CompatibleHomeViewWrapper(viewModel: viewModel)
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 14, *)
private struct HomeViewWrapper: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: HomeViewModel

    var body: some View {
        CompatibleHomeView(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
}

private struct CompatibleHomeViewWrapper: View {
    @State var viewModel: HomeViewModel

    var body: some View {
        CompatibleHomeView(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
}

struct CompatibleHomeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: HomeViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.someRandomName)
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `@ObservedObject` is very similar and is supported in iOS 13

Comment: Actually in such case I don't see necessity of HomeViewWrapper at all. StateObject wrapper is needed when object is created internally, but you have external ownership, even out of parent view, so state object is not needed, because HomeViewModel is not recreated on view rebuild.

Comment: @loremipsum. Yes, `@ObservedObject` is similar but it is all over Apple's documentation and in the WWDC videos that this is what we should not use. 

`@ObservedObject` is only for when we do have ownership over the resource.

Comment: @Asperi. While HomeView does not create the HomeViewModel it does have ownership over it. The HomeViewModel is created and passed into the HomeView that will then own it.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the @StateObject behaviour by wrapping a custom propertyWrapper around @State and @ObservedObject like so:

```swift
import Combine
import PublishedObject // https://github.com/Amzd/PublishedObject

/// A property wrapper type that instantiates an observable object.
@propertyWrapper
public struct StateObject<ObjectType: ObservableObject>
where ObjectType.ObjectWillChangePublisher == ObservableObjectPublisher {
    
    /// Wrapper that helps with initialising without actually having an ObservableObject yet
    private class ObservedObjectWrapper: ObservableObject {
        @PublishedObject var wrappedObject: ObjectType? = nil
        init() {}
    }
    
    private var thunk: () -> ObjectType
    @ObservedObject private var observedObject = ObservedObjectWrapper()
    @State private var state = ObservedObjectWrapper()
    
    public var wrappedValue: ObjectType {
        if state.wrappedObject == nil {
            // There is no State yet so we need to initialise the object
            state.wrappedObject = thunk()
        }
        if observedObject.wrappedObject == nil {
            // Retrieve the object from State and observe it in ObservedObject
            observedObject.wrappedObject = state.wrappedObject
        }
        return state.wrappedObject!
    }
    
    public init(wrappedValue thunk: @autoclosure @escaping () -> ObjectType) {
        self.thunk = thunk
    }
}
```

I use this myself too so I will keep it updated at:
https://gist.github.com/Amzd/8f0d4d94fcbb6c9548e7cf0c1493eaff

---

**Note:** The most upvoted comment was that ObservedObject was very similar, which is just not true at all.

`StateObject` retains the object between view inits AND relays object changes to the view through willChangeObserver.

`ObservedObject` only relays changes to the view BUT if you create it in the view init, every time the parent view changes the object will be initialised again (losing your state).

This explanation is very crude and there is better out there please read up on it as it is an impactful part of SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct StateObjectView<ViewModel: ObservableObject, Content: View>: View {
    let viewModel: ViewModel
    let content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if #available(iOS 14, *) {
                StateObjectView14(viewModel: viewModel, content: content)
            } else {
                StateObjectView13(viewModel: viewModel, content: content)
            }
        }
        
    }
}

@available(iOS 14.0, *)

struct StateObjectView14<ViewModel: ObservableObject, Content: View>: View {
    
    @SwiftUI.StateObject var viewModel : ViewModel

    let content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        content()
            .environmentObject(viewModel)
    }
}
struct StateObjectView13<ViewModel: ObservableObject, Content: View>: View {
    @Backport.StateObject var viewModel : ViewModel
    let content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        content()
            .environmentObject(viewModel)

    }
}
```

##### Usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var reset = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("reset") {
                reset.toggle()
            }
            ScoreView()
        }
    }
}
class ScoreViewModel: ObservableObject {
    init() {
        //score = 0
        print("Model Created")
    }
    @Published var score: Int = 0
}
struct ScoreView: View {
    let viewModel : ScoreViewModel = .init()

    var body: some View {
        StateObjectView(viewModel: viewModel) {
            ScoreContentView()
        }
        .onAppear {
            print("ScoreView Appear")
        }
    }
}
struct ScoreContentView: View {
    //@ObservedObject var viewModel : ScoreViewModel = .init()
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel : ScoreViewModel
    @State private var niceScore = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Button("Add Score") {
                
                viewModel.score += 1
                print("viewModel.score: \(viewModel.score)")
                if viewModel.score > 3 {
                    niceScore = true
                }
            }
            
            Text("Content Score: \(viewModel.score)")
            Text("Nice? \(niceScore ? "YES" : "NO")")

        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

Backports:
https://github.com/shaps80/SwiftUIBackports